# Configure Tomcat With Script

Tags: java, tomcat

I am working with a Java project that requires over 100 jar's be added to the class path on the tomcat server.  I am looking to automate this process, and I haven't had any luck Googleing.  Is there any way to script the configuration of a tomcat server?

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: Alternatively, is there a better approach than adding all of the jars to the class path?

Comment: what is issue here , tomcat is not able to load 100 jars in class path , or there is some problem to put jar in classpath for tomcat.

Comment: The purpose is to make it easier to set up new environments to run this project.

Comment: what build tool are you using?

Comment: I have experience with Ant and would like to use that.